# Socket.EndReceive workflow

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

On [microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-an-asynchronous-server-socket) you can find this code for `ReadCallback(IAsyncResult)`

```
static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    int read = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if(read > 0)
    {
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, read));
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }
    else
    {
        if(state.sb.Length > 1)
        {
            string content = state.sb.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine($"Read {content.Length} bytes from socket. \nData: {content}");
        }
        handler.Close();
    }
}
```

What is unclear to me is this `if/else` statement. Why do we `BeginReceive` again if we already read something?

Why do not we just do

```
static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    int read = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, read));

    if(state.sb.Length > 1)
    {
        string content = state.sb.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine($"Read {content.Length} bytes from socket. \nData: {content}");
    }
    handler.Close();
}
```

Comment: Microsoft socket tutorials are ridiculously bad. Do not learn from this. This code is the worst way you can do it. Find a few socket tutorials on the web and develop your own thoughts about what way looks best.

Comment: @usr doing it right now. Testing and playing with 2 console applications :)

Comment: I am about to answer your bounty question.

Comment: @usr I am glad, yayy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, because partial messages are a thing.

If, for example, you send 1000 bytes, then the first receive may actually only get 30.  Then the next gets 70, the next gets 100, then 50, then 150, etc. until all 1000 bytes are received (obviously the numbers would be higher with modern networks).  This is why most TCP messages have some kind of end marker, or they come prefixed with their size: so you know when they're complete.

Just remember:  Even if you request 100 bytes, EndReceive will give you *up to* that many bytes.  It doesn't necessarily wait until it has them all.

Comment: I get that part but how doesn `EndReceive` (Socket) knows how many bytes he already has received when i call it again?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... It knows how many bytes you requested and how many it actually got.  But that's it.  And the only thing separate requests share is the state object that they know nothing about.  Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Let's say i send 5 bytes. I call `BeginReceive` which stores bytes into buffer BUT it only got first, second and third byte. Inside callback function i check if it read something and if it does i call `BeginReceive` again  since maybe there is more data but now how does `BeginReceive` know it need to starts from byte 3 and continue reading? Why doesn't it start from byte 0 and again read 2-3 bytes and do that infinity time. Instead it knows it already read 3 bytes and start reading from byte 3 (index 2). I mean i understand what it does, but trying to figure out how.

Comment: Gotcha.  Each time you get the buffer from EndReceive, it resets it all.  The buffer is reset and it starts at zero again.  So, you need to move your data out of the buffer between calls and assemble it yourself.  Because you're right; it doesn't know.  That's why the example appends it to state.sb each time;  because that's the actual repository for the received data.